# Color of the lines

Tags: android, canvas, colors, draw

I'm writing an app for Android, what works with rhythms. I've tried to make two lines where the app draws the original rate of the rhythm and the other draws what you've hit back.

It's working fine until I try to color the indicator lines of the players try.

```
for (int i = 0; i < gameosszido.size()-1; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            startx = 0;
            starty = 0;
            endx = startx;
            endy = 50;
            canvas.drawLine(startx, starty, endx, endy, paint);
        }
        else
        {
line 433     if ((gameTimes.get(i-1) < hezagTimes.get(i-1)*1.25 && gameTimes.get(i-1) > hezagTimes.get(i-1)*0.85))
            {
                paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            else if (gameTimes.get(i-1) < hezagTimes.get(i-1)*1.45 && gameTimes.get(i-1) > hezagTimes.get(i-1)*0.55)
            {
                paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            }
            else
            {
                paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            }
            double d = (double)gameosszido.get(i);
            double c = (double)gameosszido.get(gameosszido.size()-2);
            startx = (int) (1050*(d/c));
            starty = 0;
            endx = startx;
            endy = 50;
            canvas.drawLine(startx, starty, endx, endy, paint);
        }
    }
```

It gives the following error:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: hu.qnszt.rhythmapp,  PID: 2646 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5 
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411) 
at u.qnszt.rhythmapp.GameActivity.drawLineHit(GameActivity.java:433) 
at hu.qnszt.rhythmapp.GameActivity.VerifyGame(GameActivity.java:194) 
at hu.qnszt.rhythmapp.GameActivity$3.onClick(GameActivity.java:134) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is that one of your `ArrayList` `gameTimes` or `hezagTimes` does´t have the correct Size, to fix this you need to make the size of this 2 `ArrayList` at least `gameosszido.size()-1`. As this is the last position that you will access. If you complete your code with the whole class I could help more, but that my guess.